# Return missing records from 1 SQL statement compare to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

- My T-SQL statement A returns 1100 rows when I add an extra JOIN in.
- My T-SQL statement B returns 990 rows when I don't have that extra JOIN.

The two statements are identical besides for the extra JOIN on statement A.

How can I return just the 110 records from the two T-SQL statements that are not in the result set of statement B?

Comment: No need to see it, just want to return what records are not in the other. Table structure or layout will not make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean [EXCEPT or INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Can't be more specific without seeing your query, but this is the general idea:

```
SELECT 
  a.*
FROM 
( 
    --statement A
) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    --statement B
) b 
  ON a.pk = b.pk
WHERE b.pk IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to post same query or similer query as per your requirement then u will get right answer 
try the below one

```
select TBL1.c1.........TBL2.c1 ........... from TBL1 left join TBL2 on TBL1.pkcolumn=TB2.PKcolumn where TBL2.COLUMN is null
```